# Swift: Convert MKPolygon to UIBeizerpath and draw path on UIView

Tags: ios, swift, mkpolygon, geoswift

I have a geojson file containing a FeatureCollection of Features. I parse the json with GEOSwift and end up having MKPolygon objects.

I have managed to draw the polygons as overlay to the MKMapView, but the performance is really poor!

The geojson file I have contains a path to every country in the world. So I actually don't need the map since I just want to draw the polygons directly to a UIView. Here's my code to getting the MKPolygon:

```
func drawPolygonsFromFeatures(_ features: Features) {
    var i = 0
    for feature in features {
        if let geometries = feature.geometries {
            for geometry in geometries {
                if let shapesCollection = geometry.mapShape() as? MKShapesCollection {
                    let shapes = shapesCollection.shapes
                    for shape in shapes {
                        if let polygon = shape as? MKPolygon {
                            if let identifier = feature.id as? String,  self.countryDict.count > 0 {
                                // Set title in order to set color on country
                                polygon.title = self.countryDict[identifier]
                            }

                            main {
                                // TODO: Draw polygons on view
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        i += 1
    }
}
```

I know it's possible to draw shapes with UIBeizerPath, but I don't know how to convert my MKPolygon to something that could show a shape on an UIView.

Comment: I created an issue in the GEOSwift github as well: https://github.com/GEOSwift/GEOSwift/issues/129